# CSS Selector not working on elements within a div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="formFields">
     <label> Field 1: </label>
     <input type="text" value="" name="field1" />
</div>
```

And my CSS selectors are as follows:

```
#formFields {clear:both;}
#formFields label {font-weight:bold;}
```

The `clear:both;` is being applied to the div, but the `font-weight:bold;` is not being applied to the labels. How would I apply this `font-weight` to the labels?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the moment, none of the rules is being applied to the div.

- `#` is the ID selector
- `.` would be the class selector

so you'll either have to give the rules the class selector

```
.formFields
```

or give the div the ID `formFields`:

```
<div id="formFields">
```